# MVC web api in sharepoint 2013 farm solution

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, rest, farm-solution, mvc

How to consume the MVC web api in SharePoint 2013 farm solution? When I try to consume with `httpclient` I cannot refer to the assembly `WebApiRestService.WebApiClient`, it's showing error as not strong named.

Comment: are you developing for SharePoint Apps?

Comment: no actually i want it in sharepoint farm solution for doing the web api call in layout pages